# status code 400 when using Clarifai's FACE_DETECT_MODEL

Tags: reactjs, api, http-status-code-400, clarifai

i am using Clarifai's Api to detect faces in an image it was working fine and i deployed it to github pages. after some time it stopped working and started giving me status code 400 and status code 10020 at the network tab although i am using the correct image format that Clarifai wants which is base64. at the same time my app uses the Clarifai's apparels detection model which works perfectly fine.

below is the relevant code:

```
import React from 'react';

import Clarifai from 'clarifai';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { setFaceBoundary, setApparelBoundary, numberOfFaces, setBoundingBox, setApparelsInfo, setWithSpinner } from '../../redux/box/box.actions';
import { setImageDimensions } from '../../redux/image/image.actions.js';

import './models-options.styles.css';

const app = new Clarifai.App({
    apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY'
    });

const ModelsOptions = ({ setFaceBoundary, setApparelBoundary, fileProperties, numberOfFaces, setBoundingBox, setApparelsInfo, setWithSpinner, setImageDimensions })=> {

        const calculateApparel = (data) => {
            const conceptsArray = data.outputs[0].data.regions.map(concepts => concepts.data.concepts);
            setApparelsInfo(conceptsArray)
            const outputs = data.outputs[0].data.regions.map(apparels => apparels.region_info.bounding_box);
            console.log(outputs);
            setBoundingBox(outputs)
            const image = document.getElementById("inputImage");
            console.log('image dimensions' ,image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight);
            const width = image.naturalWidth;
            const height = image.naturalHeight;
            const apparelsLoaction = outputs.map(apparel => { 
                    return {
                        leftCol: apparel.left_col * width,
                        topRow: apparel.top_row * height,
                        rightCol: width -  apparel.right_col * width,
                        bottomRow: height - apparel.bottom_row * height
                    }
                });
            return apparelsLoaction;
    }

    const calculateFace = (data) => {
            const faceNumber = data.outputs[0].data.regions.length;
            numberOfFaces(faceNumber);
            const outputs = data.outputs[0].data.regions.map((faces) => faces.region_info.bounding_box);
            setBoundingBox(outputs);
            const image = document.getElementById("inputImage");
            const width = image.clientWidth;
            const height = image.clientHeight;
            const faceCordinates = outputs.map((face) => {
                    return {
                        leftCol: face.left_col * width,
                        topRow: face.top_row * height,
                        rightCol: width -  face.right_col * width,
                        bottomRow: height - face.bottom_row * height,
                    }
                });
            return faceCordinates;
        }



    const detectFace = () => {
        setWithSpinner(true)
        app.models.predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, {base64: fileProperties}).then(
        (response) => {
            setFaceBoundary(calculateFace(response));
            setWithSpinner(false)

        },
        (err) => {
            console.log('There was an error', err);
        }
            );
        setApparelsInfo({});
        setApparelBoundary({});
    }

    const detectApparels = () => {
        setWithSpinner(true)
        app.models.predict('72c523807f93e18b431676fb9a58e6ad', {base64: fileProperties}).then(
        (response) => {         
            console.log('response at the  models',response)
            setApparelBoundary(calculateApparel(response));
            setWithSpinner(false)

        },
        (err) => {
            console.log('There was an error', err);
        }
            );              
        setFaceBoundary({});
        numberOfFaces(0)
    }
    return (
        <div className="models-button">
          <button onClick={detectFace}>Detect Face</button>
          <button onClick={detectApparels}>Detect Apparels</button>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({image: {fileProperties}}) => ({
    fileProperties
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setFaceBoundary: (facePostion) => dispatch(setFaceBoundary(facePostion)),
    setApparelBoundary: (apparelPosition) => dispatch(setApparelBoundary(apparelPosition)),
    numberOfFaces: (number) => dispatch(numberOfFaces(number)),
    setApparelsInfo: (number) => dispatch(setApparelsInfo(number)),
    setBoundingBox: (bounding) => dispatch(setBoundingBox(bounding)),
    setWithSpinner: (spinner) => dispatch(setWithSpinner(spinner)),
    setImageDimensions: (dimensions) => dispatch(setImageDimensions(dimensions)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ModelsOptions);
```

here is a link to the webApp if it might help: https://abdullahgumi.github.io/smart-box/

any idea on how to solve this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks like an internal issue - hopefully will be resolved soon.  Will let you know ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was an internal issue that now should be resolved.  The webApp you've linked to is now working.

There is also a status page for the models at [Clarifai Model Status Page](https://status.clarifai.com/) which might be helpful, although in this case it was not reflecting the status of that model accurately unfortunately.

Comment: That was it. Now it is working. Thanks for the info

Comment: @AbdullahGumi - its helpful to mark the question as answered if you wouldn't mind; others then will be more likely to look at it if they are having the same problem.  Then we don't have to get a bunch of duplicate answers just for the Model Status Page link. :D